# How to keep language changed once a page is left

Tags: vb.net

I have a button to change English to French, and vice-versa. The button works perfectly, however, when I move to a new page in the application, the language is reset back to the original on the first page. For example, I'm on the main menu. I change it to French. Everything is good, but when I click a button to open up a sub menu, the new page opens and the main menu turns back to English. I need a way to keep the language changed until the user changes it back.

I have tried to set the current culture to French when I change languages, but this doesn't fix the issue. I have .resx files that contain all the words I need (that's how I'm translating).

```
Private Sub btnChangeLanguage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnChangeLanguage.Click
        Try
            If CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("fr-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture

            ElseIf CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I just had other global variables that I wasn't changing. I added those to the method and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help

```
Private Sub btnChangeLanguage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnChangeLanguage.Click
        Try
            If CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("fr-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "FR"

            ElseIf CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.French Then
                CurrentLanguageSelection = enumLanguage.English
                Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-CA")
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                gCurrentStrLanguage = "EN"

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store an application setting that refers to the current selected language and then reference the setting in the constructor or load event. Something along the lines of:

```
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Try
        Dim existingCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo(My.Settings.SelectedCulture)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = existingCulture
    Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show("There was an issue loading the existing culture. The language will be the default language.", "Error Loading Culture", MesssageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageBoxIcons.Warning)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the MSDN article on My.Settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object

Essentially you'd create a new application setting that is a String named SelectedCulture and set it equal to your default culture (e.g. "fr-CA"). Then in your `btnChangeLanguage` click event you'd update the setting prior to resetting the CurrentCulture of the thread.